# How to Programmatically Create new Calendars on iPhone that will sync to iCal

Tags: iphone, xcode, calendar

I'm looking for a way to create a new Calendar on the iphone device programatically. I have been looking at Event Kit and it clearly states how to create a new event in a calendar and there is also a convenient way of gathering all the calendars in code, What I can't find is how to create a new one that is saved to the device.

Any ideas'

Comment: have you found a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Check this [kal repository](https://github.com/klazuka/Kal) for creating programmatically iphone calendar same as iCal

Check this method for creating programmatically event:

```
-(void)initCalendar {

 // An array of 1 dictionary object, containing START and END values.
 NSMutableArray* pvDict  = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL    URLWithString:PV_URL ]];

 // Check if the private view event already exists in the default calendar.
 // Then set the calendar button state.

 // Get a entry point to the Calendar database.
 self.store = [[EKEventStore alloc ] init ];

 // Get an array of all the calendars.
 NSArray *calendars = store.calendars;

 // Get the default calendar, set by the user in preferences.
 EKCalendar *defaultCal = store.defaultCalendarForNewEvents;

 // Find out if this calendar is modifiable.
 BOOL isDefaultCalModifiable = defaultCal.allowsContentModifications ;

 // Create an event in the default calendar.

 self.event = [ EKEvent eventWithEventStore:store ];

 self.event.title = CHELSEA_SPACE ;
 self.event.location = CHELSEA_ADDRESS ;

 NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
 [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.S"];

 NSString *startString = [[ pvDict objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"starts" ];
 NSDate *dateStart = [dateFormatter dateFromString:startString];

 NSString *endString = [[ pvDict objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"ends" ];
 NSDate *dateEnd = [dateFormatter dateFromString:endString];

 self.event.startDate = dateStart;
 self.event.endDate   = dateEnd; 

 self.event.calendar = defaultCal ;

 // Alternative code to add 2.5 hours to start time.
 // [[NSDate alloc] initWithTimeInterval:9000 sinceDate:event.startDate];

 // Search for events which match this date/time start and end.
 // Compare the matched events by event TITLE.

 NSPredicate *predicate = [store predicateForEventsWithStartDate:event.startDate 
       endDate:event.endDate calendars:calendars];

 NSArray *matchingEvents = [store eventsMatchingPredicate:predicate];

 self.calendarButton.enabled = NO;

 if( ! isDefaultCalModifiable ) {
 // The default calendar is not modifiable
 return ;
} 

 if ( [ matchingEvents count ] > 0 ) {

  // There are already event(s) which match this date/time start and end.
  // Check if this event is the PV

  EKEvent *anEvent;  
  int j;

   for ( j=0; j < [ matchingEvents count]; j++) {

   anEvent = [ matchingEvents objectAtIndex:j ] ;
   if([ CHELSEA_SPACE isEqualToString: anEvent.title ]) {
    // PV event already exists in calendar.
    return;
   }
  }
  [ anEvent release ];
 }

 self.calendarButton.enabled = YES;

 [ pvDict release ];
}

-(void)addEventToCalendar:(id)sender {

NSError *error;
BOOL saved = [self.store saveEvent:self.event span:EKSpanThisEvent error:&error]; 

NSLog(@"Saved calendar event = %@\n", (saved ? @"YES" : @"NO"));
self.calendarButton.enabled = NO;

}
```

Comment: what you refer me to is a Calendar View where as I need to create a new EKCalendar like "work" and "home"